# ffmpeg refuses to use audio device together with video capture (gdigrab)

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to capture a recording of my screen along with sound. I have been able to peace together various SO answers and the documentation but I am struggling to put it all together.

With the following I can capture a video recording of my primary monitor:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 2560x1440 -show_region 1 -i desktop output.mp4 -y
```

I can also capture audio from a playing video with:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer" output.m4a -y
```

I want to combine the two and capture a video and its sound that is playing.

```
cffmpeg -f gdigrab audio="virtual-audio-capturer" -framerate 30 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 2560x1440 -show_region 1 -i desktop output.mkv -y
```

Gives me an error:

```
desktop: No such file or directory
```

Various other tries just return more errors. What am I doing wrong?

Also I am not particular about `dshow` or `gdigrab`, I am not sure what they are anyways. I just need it to work

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: **Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/**. Please delete this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video and audio are separate inputs. Video is accessed through the gdigrab device and audio through dshow (Directshow). So,

`ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 2560x1440 -show_region 1 -i desktop -f dshow -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer" output.mp4 -y`